# Is there a better way to store one incremented Integer in a db in a thread safe way than blocking?

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra, datamapper, nonblocking

I'm developing a Sinatra app which uses unicorn. Each worker is one thread, it loads the whole application, they just share the db. (please correct my if I'm wrong ;) )

The first thread gets the Integer, does something with it and then increments it, the second thread should not get the Integer of the first thread (thread safety), it should only get the incremented Integer.

I did that with blocking, but want to find a better approach because during my research I often read that this is a very bad way of solving my problem as it's not very scaleable.

If you want to see my whole application feel free to check it out on [github](https://github.com/wubwubwubcr3w/url-shortener-sinatra) ;)

Comment: I'm not sure about mysql (or whatever it is you're using), but this is supported natively in redis and mongodb.

Comment: can I use one of them in a single heroku dyno? (free plan)

Comment: They are available as add-ons. I'm not sure if there are free versions of those. Go check it out.

Comment: I don't want to give them my credit card essentials, so I can't use addons :/

Comment: They are available for free but in order to install any add ons you need to enter your CC credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you're trying to generate alphanumeric ids for shortened urls. If this is the case, then it's much simpler than you think

Let there be a regular auto-incrementing id integer field. When a new request comes in, you create a record in the database, get its id (which won't be repeated again and other workers won't get it), convert it to an alphanumeric form and save (to another column).

Ruby even includes conversion methods for some cases.

```
aid = 1746563

s = aid.to_s(36) # => "11fnn"
i = s.to_i(36) # => 1746563
```

You can just use your methods instead of these.

### Update

Since you mentioned that you use Posgresql, there is a perfect tool for this: [Sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html)!

You can create a sequence and then get auto-incrementing numbers from it, without worrying that another client will get the same value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it ;) You mean I should write the long url into the db, get the id (which is automatically generated and unique) and use it to generate my hash?

Comment: Something like that, yeah (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do).

Comment: hmm sounds good, I'll try it and then post what happened, thx so long :D

Comment: @your edit: I use data-mapper and the "Serial" data type for the id field. It works like a charm :D